# Build Providers in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, buildprovider

How can I determine the actual filename (App_Code_xxx.dll) of the types (classes) which is being built by my build provider.

For instance I have a build provider which injects classes based on some configuration. Say MyNameSpace.MyClass. When this build provider is consumed by the Web App. I just want to know the actual file(.dll) which was compiled on the disk by asp_net.dll in temporary files.

In true sense I even want to control the naming for this file.

### Thanks in Advance.

Mohammed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never liked the website build approach that came with Visual Studio 2005 that created a new file named App_Code_xxx.dll every time you build, it's just pain to work with it.

Visual Studio 2005 SP1 (and later versions) have a web application which builds your project into a single .dll (like was done in .net 1.1) and is much easier to work with, I would recommend comverting your website to web application. Tutorials are available [here](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/migration2/migration2.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(VS.80).aspx)

This way you don't have to worry about the filename that was written on disk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that YourClass is defined in  YourDll.dll, then you can use the following code:

```
  var assembly= Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourClass);
  string dllName=assembly.GetName().Name;  
  Assert.AreEqual("YourDll", dllName);
```